# Can't connect airpods on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth

I can see the airpods as not set up in the bluetooth settings but when I try to connect to the airpods while they're in pairing mode, it doesn't work. The airpods connect fine to my android phone.

Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 2):

you can use this: https://www.raymondjdouglas.com/blog/2019/airpods-on-arch/

Open a shell and do the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Or

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Uncomment and manually set ControllerMode to BR/EDR:

```
# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
ControllerMode = dual
```

Restart the bluetooth service:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```